# Nextjs app directory doesnt not have getStaticPats

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

I ran into an issue with the new nextjs app router

where i wanted to use SSG pages for stapi blog but was getting this error when building

```
app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx
Type error: Page "app/blog/[slug]/page.tsx" does not match the required types of a Next.js Page.
  "getStaticPaths" is not a valid Page export field.
```

for

```
import { BlogArticlePreview } from "@/components/landingPages/BlogArticles";
import { getBlog, getBlogs } from "@/services/strapi/modules/blog";
import { BlogPage } from "./BlogPage";

const fetchBlog = async (slug: string) => {
  try {
    return await getBlog(slug);
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const data = await getBlogs();

  const paths = (data as any).data.map((item: any) => {
    return {
      params: { slug: item.attributes.slug },
    };
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  };
};

export default async function Page({ params }: any) {
  const blog = ((await fetchBlog(params.slug)) as any)
    ?.attributes as unknown as BlogArticlePreview;

  return <BlogPage {...blog} />;
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to do so

Method:

> generateStaticParams

Example:

```
import { BlogArticlePreview } from "@/components/landingPages/BlogArticles";
import { getBlog, getBlogs } from "@/services/strapi/modules/blog";
import { BlogPage } from "./BlogPage";

const fetchBlog = async (slug: string) => {
  try {
    return await getBlog(slug);
  } catch (error) {
    return null;
  }
};

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  const data = await getBlogs();

  return (data as any).data.map((item: any) => {
    return { slug: item.attributes.slug };
  });
}

export default async function Page({ params }: any) {
  const blog = ((await fetchBlog(params.slug)) as any)
    ?.attributes as unknown as BlogArticlePreview;

  return <BlogPage {...blog} />;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are using the `App Router` which replaced the `getStaticPaths` with `generateStaticParams`. Check the [migration guide](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/upgrading/app-router-migration#dynamic-paths-getstaticpaths).

Comment: yes got it thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
export async function getStaticPaths()
```

Comment: still the same issue